# How to create your close button on an access database report

Tags: ms-access

I have a database which I want to remove the default title bar which contains the minimize, maximize and close buttons.

It works when borders are set to none.

But I need to get a custom close button on the report just like on the forms.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `Command Button` and `CloseWindow` macro command to report.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. I noticed my reports were all in print preview that’s why it wasn’t working earlier. Thanks so much. I really appreciate.

Comment: You found the answer helpful then please mark the answer accepted (tick mark) so that other visitor can know it solved.

Comment: How is that done here? Because am new here

Comment: Just tick mark my answer. You will find a tick symbol left top corner of every answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like form you can use same `Command Button` control to close report.

- Take command button control to report (in design mode).
- Use `CloseWindow` macro command to close current report.

[image]

- In case of printing you can hide the button from print. Set `Display When` property `Screen Only`.

[CommandButton.DisplayWhen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.commandbutton.displaywhen) property.

[image]